# Error when trying to run a project with ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I cloned a repository with git clone and it downloaded to my computer, I used the npm install command and it installs some things but with the message

```
npm WARN deprecated" and at the end it says "55 vulnerabilities (3 low, 12 moderate, 36 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run: npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

I've already used

```
npm install --force
```

but when using "ionic serve" it doesn't connect and appears this:

```
[ng] (node:13200) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
[ng] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[ng] node:internal/crypto/hash:71
[ng]   this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
[ng]                   ^
[ng] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[ng]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[ng]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
[ng]     at module.exports (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
[ng]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
[ng]     at C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
[ng]     at C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
[ng]     at C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11   
[ng]     at C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19   
[ng]     at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:47:13)
[ng]     at processResource (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
[ng]     at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
[ng]     at runLoaders (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
[ng]     at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
[ng]     at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
[ng]     at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
[ng]     at C:\Users\ritle\Desktop\App Sensorial\Nova pasta\AnaliseSensorial\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {        
[ng]   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
[ng]   library: 'digital envelope routines',
[ng]   reason: 'unsupported',
[ng]   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
[ng] }
[ng] Node.js v18.12.1

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

How i solve this?

I tried npm install / npm install --force and npm audit fix --force but dont work

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm cache clean` to clear the cache of the downloaded packages, then run `npm install` again.

If this doesn't work it is most likely a problem with the node version you have installed, try different versions and see if it works (best bet is to check the git repo you are trying to clone for node version compatibility)

Comment: hello, did not work